# Load cell changing over time

Tags: gpio, python, pi-2, sensor, python-3

I'm using a 1kg load cell beam (see example at bottom) connected to a HX711 board then connected to the Raspberry GPIO.

I'm running this Python3 code: https://github.com/gandalf15/HX711/blob/master/HX711_Python3/simple_example.py (but added a loop to continuing reading the output and displaying it)

I then hang a small weight from the beam (about 50g) and left it hanging.

The problem is that overtime the sensor reading is significantly changing.  It started outputting at about 105,000 and then over the course of 8 hours has not dropped to showing only 75,000 with the same weight...

There has been no significant environment changes.

Is the sensor broken or what could the problem be?

[image]

Comment: My first thought is that the beam's physical characteristic changes, nothing to do with anything else. It is my instinct, nothing else. I know it sounds silly. But perhaps I should use my HX711 digital weight gear: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511749/load-cell-adc-hx711-alternativesto do an experiment, say put a load on it and watch it again after 8 hours, and see if anything changes.

Comment: don't stop the experiment in the middle ... remove the weight and continue monitoring the output